# How to retrieve data from different screen?

Tags: blackberry

I have two Screens Screen1 and Screen 2.
Screen1 contains a LabelField1  and a Button "ok".
Screen2 contains a LabelField2.
When the ok button is clicked the text in LabelField1 should be displayed in LabelField2(Screen1 should be popped and Screen2 should be opened).

Comment: when you click ok button on screen 1, close screen 1 and open new screen 2 and pass the value of label 1 to screen 2.

Comment: I have closed screen1 and opened screen2, but how to pass the value to screen2. @Signare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

//This will close current screen.

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
```

Then pass the value of label 1 to screen 2.

```java
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new screen2(value_of_label1));
```

And in the screen 2 class, just display the string value.

```java
public class screen2 extends MainScreen{
    public screen2(String label1_value){
        // TODO: create label field first
        LabelField2.setText(label1_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, I do not recommend the use of "Screen screen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()" to identify the screen to be closed.  You should know the screen to be closed, it is normally the current screen, so you can use a form of 'this', e.g. "UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this)".  At the instant the getActiveScreen() is executed, the active screen could be another screen, like a menu popup or a ObjectChoiceField popup,  so using 'this' or identifying the screen specifically is safer.  It is also clearer when reading the code.  Just my 1p worth.

Comment: Well, without popping Screen1 I can push Screen2 to the top of the display stack, but if I use popScreen(this), I am getting an error "The method popScreen(Screen) in the type UiApplication is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){})",                   or else if I create a new object to Screen2 and popScreen, it throws "Illegal argument Exception". @Signare

Comment: Well, Thanks I got it, But if I have more values to be passed, should I pass everything as the parameters of Screen2 constructor or is there any other way. @Signare

Comment: I have a different approach. For me, it is always good to separate data from the User interface.  So I would create a Data Object and provide a mechanism that enables both Screens (and any other screens that your application might have) to share this Object. In this case you could create this shared Object at start up time and provide this Data Object as a parameter to both screens.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got a different information
As I said before, two Screens(classes), Screen1 and Screen2.
Let the strings to be passed from Screen1 be name and id.
Let Screen2 contains label1 and label2 for displaying,
We can just use the following code,

```
label1.setText(Screen1.name);
add(label1);
label2=new LabelField(Screen1.id);
add(label2);
```

Now the values of name and Id from Screen1 will be displayed in both the labels in Screen2

Comment: I would avoid using this approach. It will only work when Screen 2 knows about Screen 1, the variables are public and either the variables are static or there is a reference to screen 1 passed to screen 2. I think it is better to create a shared data object that both screens know about and not expose the inner workings of Screen 1.

Comment: @PeterStrange  Can you please brief the above comment with a sample program.